# CSS Keyboard Layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a small dynamic keyboard with characters only but I am a bit lost.

First, here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/45zDd

As you can see, it's nearly done, but the second and the third row need a margin or something, so that it looks like a real keyboard.

Is this possible, because well, it's a table, so I don't think it's possible to give a row a margin, right? If it's not possible, do you know another dynamic way how I can create that simple keyboard layout without Javascript?

**CSS:**

```
.keyboard {
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
}

.keyboardRow {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

.key {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="keyboard">
    <div class="keyboardRow">
        <span class="key">Q</span>
        <span class="key">W</span>
        <span class="key">E</span>
        <span class="key">R</span>
        <span class="key">T</span>
        <span class="key">Y</span>
        <span class="key">U</span>
        <span class="key">I</span>
        <span class="key">O</span>
        <span class="key">P</span>
    </div>
    <div class="keyboardRow">
        <span class="key">A</span>
        <span class="key">S</span>
        <span class="key">D</span>
        <span class="key">F</span>
        <span class="key">G</span>
        <span class="key">H</span>
        <span class="key">J</span>
        <span class="key">K</span>
        <span class="key">L</span>
    </div>
    <div class="keyboardRow">
        <span class="key">Z</span>
        <span class="key">X</span>
        <span class="key">C</span>
        <span class="key">V</span>
        <span class="key">B</span>
        <span class="key">N</span>
        <span class="key">M</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the keyboard in front of you. Does it look like the keys are arranged like a table? Of course not ;) So don't use `display:table`.

Comment: You could use `block` for the table and rows, and `inline-block` for the cells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just using this CSS:

```
.keyboardRow { text-align:center }
.key { display:inline-block; border:1px solid red; padding:10px;margin-bottom:5px; }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4qa7/)**

Comment: And going on Nick's answer for just for a bit of fun, I've made it more "keyboard like" http://jsfiddle.net/u4qa7/2/

Comment: Haha nice, it's like PC keyboard vs Mac :')

Comment: Thank you :D but is there a way that the keys fill out my whole keyboard-container div? Or is it only possible by changing the padding?

Comment: @Termi2610 Well you can either change the `padding`, or set a `width` and `height` on the `.key` class

Comment: @Nick R Okay thank you again, was hoping that theres a way to make that more dynamic so the keys will fill their parent container. Prob need some js here

Comment: Sooo, it's done. http://jsfiddle.net/yzgkw The size of the keys depend now on the keyboard container size. For the design you should check out the cool jsfiddles above. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed. http://jsfiddle.net/5zshz1hr/ improved it a bit, adding a "blank" key at the end of the third row to move the buttons to match a keyboard and added a fixed width.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a lit late! But how about this one :

**CSS**

```
.KeyboardRow {
text-align: center;
 }
.KeyboardKey {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
color: #777777;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
width: 75px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}


.KeyboardKey:hover {
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
background-color: #dfdfdf;
  }

.KeyboardKey:active {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
 }
.KeyboardRow .active {
background-color: #0c57a8;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #9fc5f2;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #9fc5f2;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #9fc5f2;
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0c57a8), color-stop(1, #043078) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0c57a8 5%, #043078 100% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0c57a8', endColorstr='#043078');
border: 1px solid #2358a1;
display: inline-block;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #07294a;
color: #ffffff;
}
.KeyboardRow .active:hover {
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #043078), color-stop(1, #0c57a8) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #043078 5%, #0c57a8 100% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#043078', endColorstr='#0c57a8');
background-color: #043078;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>KeyBoard</title>
    <link href="style.keyboard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="keyboard">
        <div class="KeyboardRow">
            <span class="KeyboardKey">Q</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">W</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">E</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">R</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">T</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">Y</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">U</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">I</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">O</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">P</span>
        </div>
        <div class="KeyboardRow">
            <span class="KeyboardKey active">A</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">S</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">D</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">F</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">G</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">H</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">J</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">K</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">L</span>
        </div>
        <div class="KeyboardRow">
            <span class="KeyboardKey">Z</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">X</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">C</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">V</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">B</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">N</span>
            <span class="KeyboardKey">M</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I changed the class names in case you wanted to use this into a bigger project.
.key are not really unique names.

My fiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/ferencik/EpnL3/